# jq: pick value if field exist

Tags: jq

This is my script:

```
def pick_partOf($uids):
    (reduce $uids[] as $uid (
        {};
        . + ($uid | {(.oid1): .id})
    )) as $dict
    | map(. + { partOf: $dict[."parent-identifier-value"] } | del(..|nulls));

def pick_organization:
    {
        resourceType: "Organization",
        active: true,
        partOf: .partOf?
    };

pick_partOf($identifiers) | pick_organization
```

Problem here, is that sometimes some input objects doesn't contains `."parent-identifier-value"`, and I'm getting:

> jq: error (at rsan.json:7): Cannot index object with null

Those are my input objects:

```json
{
  "identifier-value": "61",
  "name": "name61"
}
{
  "id": "62",
  "name": "name62",
  "parent-identifier-value": "61"
}
```

Currently, I'm launching jq using empty array as `$identifiers` arg:

```
jq -s -f build-organization-bundle.jq --argjson identifiers '[]' rsan.json
```

However, my `identifiers` is an other json files like this:

```json
{
  "id": "be8a02b6-54b9-450f-bf45-f28ab7ebf2dd",
  "oid1": "61"
}
{
  "id": "f1652f3a-bca9-433c-a2c4-c924811196f6",
  "oid1": "62"
}
```

I've tried with:

```
def pick_partOf($uids):
    (reduce $uids[] as $uid (
        {};
        . + ($uid | {(.oid1): .id})
    )) as $dict
    | map(. + (
        if (.|has("parent-identifier-value")) then 
        { partOf: $dict[."parent-identifier-value"] }
        else null end
    ))
    | del(..|nulls));
```

But here I'm facing with some syntax issue I don't quite figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe you want to look into the [Error Suppression Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ErrorSuppression%2FOptionalOperator%3A%3F) `?` and the [Alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Alternativeoperator%3A%2F%2F) `//`, or the `try … catch` [construct](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#try-catch) even.

Comment: You didn't say what you want to do when it doesn't exist

Comment: Note that you call `pick_partOf` for each each object of your input, so you  build are `$dict` for each object of your input.

Comment: Tip: `. | ...` is a weird way to write `...`

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify why you want `pick_partOf` to achieve.

If its output should be

```json
{
  "identifier-value": "61",
  "name": "name61"
}
{
  "id": "62",
  "name": "name62",
  "parent-identifier-value": "61",
  "partOf": "be8a02b6-54b9-450f-bf45-f28ab7ebf2dd"
}
```

then you can use

```
if ."parent-identifier-value" then
   .partOf = $dict[."parent-identifier-value"]
else
   .
end
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7tYNQ8TtA8) on jqplay

Repeating `."parent-identifier-value"` was annoying me.

```
."parent-identifier-value" as $piv |
if $piv then .partOf = $dict[$piv] else . end
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yHHNJWyRLg) on jqplay